# Pydub - How to change frame rate without changing playback speed

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, frame-rate, pydub

I have a couple audio files that I open in Pydub with `AudioSegment`.

I want to decrease the audio quality from frame rate 22050 to 16000 Hz. (One channel files)

If I simply change the frame rate of AudioSegment, what I get is the exact same wave played in slower speed. Well, fair enough.

But how do I actually change the waves to fit a lower quality, same speed playback?

(Manual interpolation is the only thing I can think of, but I don't want to get into that trouble)

Comment: Have you tried AudioSegment().set_frame_rate() ?

Comment: Would you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(…)
sound = sound.set_frame_rate(16000)
```

Comment: That's much easier than what I was doing: `subprocess.check_output(['sox',filename,'-r','16000',new_filename])`

Comment: I made a mistake in trying to implement this, maybe it can save some time for others reading the answer: I tried `sound.set_frame_rate(16000)` thinking it would apply the operation on the `sound` object which could afterwards be exported. However, as correctly stated in this answer, you need to assign the result to a (new or existing) variable, so `sound = sound.set_frame_rate(16000)`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this instead also:

```py
import librosa

y, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=16000)
```

and use it further as per your requirement.