# How to change audio playback speed using Pydub?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, wav, pydub

I am new learner of audio editing libs - [Pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub). I want to change some audio files' playback speed using Pydub(say .wav/mp3 format files), but I don't know how to make it. The only module I saw that could possibly deal with this problem is [speedup module in effect.py](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/effects.py#L53). However, there is no explanation about how I am supposed to call it.

Could anyone kindly explain how to do this task in Pydub? Many thanks!

(A related question: [Pydub - How to change frame rate without changing playback speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035217/pydub-how-to-change-frame-rate-without-changing-playback-speed), but what I want to do is to change the playback speed without changing the audio quality.)

Comment: Specifically, I don't understand the arguments in `speedup(seg, playback_speed=1.5, chunk_size=150, crossfade=25)`, especially `chunk_size` and `crossfade`. Could anyone kindly explain them? Thanks!

Comment: Chunk size and crossfade are optional - you can just leave them out :) - a playback speed of 1.5 will play 1.5x faster than the original sound. The way it works is it splits the sound into chunks (150ms long by default) and then overlaps them to shorten the total playback duration (with crossfades of 25ms, be default)

Answer (score 6):

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub import effects

root = r'audio.wav'
velocidad_X = 1.5 # No puede estar por debajo de 1.0

sound = AudioSegment.from_file(root)
so = sound.speedup(velocidad_X, 150, 25)
so.export(root[:-4] + '_Out.mp3', format = 'mp3')
```

Comment: This worked a lot better than other solutions I've found! Thank you.

Comment: This actually seems to work but the quality is so bad

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using pyrubberband package which requires rubberband library that can stretch audio while keeping the pitch and high quality. I was able to install the library on MacOS using brew, and same on Ubuntu with apt install. For extreme stretching, look into PaulStretch

```
brew install rubberband
```

This works simply with librosa package

```
import librosa
import pyrubberband
import soundfile as sf

y, sr = librosa.load(filepath, sr=None)
y_stretched = pyrubberband.time_stretch(y, sr, 1.5)
sf.write(analyzed_filepath, y_stretched, sr, format='wav')
```

To make pyrubberband work directly with AudioSegment from pydub without librosa I fiddled this function:

```
def change_audioseg_tempo(audiosegment, tempo, new_tempo):
    y = np.array(audiosegment.get_array_of_samples())
    if audiosegment.channels == 2:
        y = y.reshape((-1, 2))

    sample_rate = audiosegment.frame_rate

    tempo_ratio = new_tempo / tempo
    print(tempo_ratio)
    y_fast = pyrb.time_stretch(y, sample_rate, tempo_ratio)

    channels = 2 if (y_fast.ndim == 2 and y_fast.shape[1] == 2) else 1
    y = np.int16(y_fast * 2 ** 15)

    new_seg = pydub.AudioSegment(y.tobytes(), frame_rate=sample_rate, sample_width=2, channels=channels)

    return new_seg
```

Comment: Thanks -- any idea about inter-operability between `pyrubberband`/`librosa` and `pydub`?

Comment: @lefft sorry I don't know. I haven't worked with either of these 3 since posting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I wrote a program to convert mp3 to different playback speed.

First, Convert the .MP3 -> .Wav because PYRubberBand supports only .wav format. Then streach the time and pitch at the same time to avoid chipmunk effect.

```
import wave
import sys
from pydub import AudioSegment
#sound = AudioSegment.from_file("deviprasadgharpehai.mp3")
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(sys.argv[1])
sound.export("file.wav", format="wav")

print(sys.argv[1])

import soundfile as sf
import pyrubberband as pyrb
y, sr = sf.read("file.wav")
# Play back at extra low speed
y_stretch = pyrb.time_stretch(y, sr, 0.5)
# Play back extra low tones
y_shift = pyrb.pitch_shift(y, sr, 0.5)
sf.write("analyzed_filepathX5.wav", y_stretch, sr, format='wav')

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("analyzed_filepathX5.wav")
sound.export("analyzed_filepathX5.mp3", format="mp3")

# Play back at low speed
y_stretch = pyrb.time_stretch(y, sr, 0.75)
# Play back at low tones
y_shift = pyrb.pitch_shift(y, sr, 0.75)
sf.write("analyzed_filepathX75.wav", y_stretch, sr, format='wav')

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("analyzed_filepathX75.wav")
sound.export("analyzed_filepathX75.mp3", format="mp3")

# Play back at 1.5X speed
y_stretch = pyrb.time_stretch(y, sr, 1.5)
# Play back two 1.5x tones
y_shift = pyrb.pitch_shift(y, sr, 1.5)
sf.write("analyzed_filepathX105.wav", y_stretch, sr, format='wav')

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("analyzed_filepathX105.wav")
sound.export("analyzed_filepathX105.mp3", format="mp3")

# Play back at same speed
y_stretch = pyrb.time_stretch(y, sr, 1)
# Play back two smae-tones
y_shift = pyrb.pitch_shift(y, sr, 1)
sf.write("analyzed_filepathXnormal.wav", y_stretch, sr, format='wav')

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("analyzed_filepathXnormal.wav")
sound.export("analyzed_filepathXnormal.mp3", format="mp3")
```

**Make Sure to install **

***Wave, AudioSegment, FFmpeg, PYRubberBand, Soundfile***

To use this Run,

**python3 *filename.py* *mp3filename.mp3***

Comment: Hi, why is y_stretch not passed to pitch_shift function? when you write the result, you seem to use only y_stretch. Could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 1):

First install ffmpeg from ffmpeg download page https://ffmpeg.org/download.html , then extract the zip file and rename it ffmpeg, then move the renamed ffmpeg folder in the C drive. Then go to control panel -> environment variables -> path -> edit ->  new -> C:\ffmpeg\bin , then click ok
Then do pip install ffmpeg

```
from pydub import utils, AudioSegment
from pydub.effects import speedup
def get_prober_name():
    return "C://ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe"


AudioSegment.converter = "C://ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"                  
utils.get_prober_name = get_prober_name
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("output.mp3",format="mp3")
final = speedup(sound, playback_speed=1.5) 
# speeds up the audio track by scale of 1.5
final.export("final.mp3",format="mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the speed of the audio without changing the pitch (or creating chipmunk effect). You can use below code.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.effects import speedup

audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(song.mp3)
new_file = speedup(audio,1.5,150)
new_file.export("file.mp3", format="mp3")
```