# Implementation of cross correlation function for pitch frequency detection

Tags: python, signal-processing, cross-correlation, pitch-detection

For my sound processing project (specifically pitch detection) I need to implement a cross correlation function and I'm having trouble with the results, I have 400 frames and all frames have 512 samples, the frames have 50 percent overlap [this is the formula of the cross correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaUUj.jpg) 
I have tried so many ways to do it correct but i couldn't here is my last code:

```py
import numpy as np

    
def pitch_detection(self, frame_matrix, frame_number, lag_vector, frequency):
        np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
        pitch_freq_vector = []
        for frame in range(frame_number):
            ccf = [] 
            frame_expand_1 = frame_matrix[frame-1, :]
            frame_expand_2 = frame_matrix[frame-2, :]
            temp_corr_1 = frame_matrix[frame, :]
            temp_corr_2 = np.append(frame_expand_1[256:], temp_corr_1, axis=0)
            temp_corr_2 = np.append(frame_expand_2[192:256], temp_corr_2, axis=0)
            len_tc2 = len(temp_corr_2)
            for lag in lag_vector: #pitch is the highest correlation in lag vector
                ccf.append(np.sum(temp_corr_1*temp_corr_2[len_tc2-lag-512:len_tc2-lag]))
            max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(ccf), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
            if max(ccf) > 0.3*np.sum(np.power(temp_corr_1, 2)): #if more than 30 detect pitch
                pitch_freq_vector.append(max_index)
            else:
                pitch_freq_vector.append(-1)
        return pitch_freq_vector
```

The problem is the maximum always is in the last arg of the `ccf` but it should vary in different frames.
note that pitch frequency for human varies between 50-400 the index of vector maps into those frequencies later and for frames that has no pitch `-1` is appended to the list

**The implementation works properly**
It should be used for a frame matrix input
I hope you enjoy it

Comment: Welcome to SO :) You should tell people the issue you encountered when trying this code, for them to help more easily

Comment: @totooooo I'm sorry , I added problem details to the question