# Match duration of two audio with each other by scaling the frame rate

Tags: python, pydub

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

# Set the paths to the audio files
file1_path = '1.wav'
file2_path = '2.wav'

# Load the audio files
file1 = AudioSegment.from_file(file1_path, format='wav')
file2 = AudioSegment.from_file(file2_path, format='wav')

# Get the duration of the audio files in seconds
original_duration = len(file1)  # in milliseconds
desired_duration = len(file2)  # in milliseconds

# Calculate the factor by which to increase the frame rate
factor =  (round(original_duration)/desired_duration)

# Increase the frame rate by the calculated factor
stretched_audio = file2.set_frame_rate(int(file2.frame_rate * factor)).speedup()

# Save the modified audio
stretched_audio.export("output.wav", format="wav")
```

This code is not working.

I want to match the duration of two audios with each other, basically trying to make it of the same length, and without trimming it.

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269959/1428679 .

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? What does it mean?

Comment: The duration of both audio is not same that's why I am saying it is not working

Comment: I don't want to do manually by changing speed