# Audio clip speed up/slow down Python

Tags: python, audio, pydub

Let's say I have two audio clips: 1a.mp3 and 1b.mp3

1a is 1.04s.
1b is 1.01s

or

1a is 1.01s. 1b is 1.04s

How can I change the speed of 1b so that the resulting clip would be the same as 1a.

Here's a visual representation of what I want to do: https://youtu.be/nyh_wBGz2Bk

I tried following this SO post but the resulting clips were not the correct length: [How to change audio playback speed using Pydub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434897/how-to-change-audio-playback-speed-using-pydub)

Here's the code I have:

```
from pydub.effects import speedup
from pydub import AudioSegment

def speed_up_audio(input_file, speed_factor):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_file)
    sped_up_audio = speedup(audio, speed_factor)
    return sped_up_audio

speed_factor = 1b_audio_len/1a_audio_len
sped_clip = speed_up_audio(1b_mp3_file_path, speed_factor)
```